# Heroku with react server side render, error "Cannot find module '../public/webpack-assets.json'

Tags: reactjs, heroku, webpack

friends:

I'm Jose. I'm trying deploy an App with the boilerplate React-Cool-Starter. This App run in dev mode as well as build it on the localhost, but in the deployment fail with the error 'Cannot find module ../public/webpack-assets.json'.
I've installed the "webpack-isomorphic-tools" library, but the problem remains.

Please, I need some idea.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you check the troubleshoots section (https://github.com/wellyshen/react-cool-starter#troubleshooting)?